# exception proof assignment operator in c++

Tags: c++, exception, variable-assignment

Below is an exception proof approach of assignment operator shared by Scott Meyer. Can anybody let me know that is it safe to delete the raw pointer?

```
int *orig =m_p; 
m_p=new int (*obj.m_p);
delete orig;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the question is that you can't tell what `m_p` contains initially. If its value has been obtained by some `&intVar`, then the answer is: NO. If the value has been produced by `new` but has already been `delete`d and not set to NULL, then the answer is NO again. If the value is undefined, the answer is another NO.

That leaves a possibilitity where it is safe.

Comment: So according to you it is not safe at all to use it? `"answer is : NO"`

Comment: Derived1(int val=0):m_p(new int (val)){*m_p=val;}

Comment: @DakshShah It is "safe" with respect to avoiding bus errors or a crash in heap memory mgmt if the deleted pointer contains an still valid heap memory address. - The other question is whether code is safe w.r.t. some exception being thrown after some new has been made and before a delete could be made. For this the *_ptr<X> you have mentioned should be good choices.

Comment: Thanks. In current situation i can't use smart pointer due to legacy code limitation.

Answer (score 0):

**If you cannot do without a raw pointer**

Yes you `have to delete it` and it is safe. You can do one more thing, which is setting it to 0 after deleting it because Setting them to 0 after deleting is a good practice, except in destructors
(because the object instance that contains the pointers is going away anyway). The standard allows deletes of NULL
pointers (it does nothing), and any good OS with memory management will cause your program to crash on the
first dereference (read or write) of a NULL pointer. So now it's up to your requirements that how you go for it

**If you can do without a raw pointer**

Raw pointer is not recommended to be used, there are other alternatives which you could go for like you can Use a managed pointer class instead of raw pointers. std::auto_ptr<>, boost::scoped_ptr<>, boost::shared_ptr<>,
boost::weak_ptr<>, boost::intrusive_ptr<>, std::unique_ptr<> (C++0x). Even on multi-million line projects with tons of memory allocation this is used and even they need to very rarely do delete anything; all the pointers are managed.

Comment: Not downvoted by me, but a "dangling effect" is not caused by not NULLing a pointer variable. It is good defensive style, because another delete won't cause any harm.

Comment: @laune Is it fine now?

Comment: @Sambuca Why so? I did answer it right? What point did i leave? He asked `is it safe` and I told him that `yes you have to if you do use it` else I do not recommend using it

Comment: so you mean to say i should set orig=NULL to make it more safe.

Comment: @user3522354 Yes, and if my answer was satisfactory please put a tick besides it